# Call posts of particular category in a page

Tags: posts, menus, pages

As per my requirement I need to call posts in a page for example Iam having a menu item `Current Tenders` and having a posts category `Current Tenders` now I need lo display posts related to current tenders in my page's content so that when Current tenders is clicked all the posts of current tenders will be displayed is there any chance of calling categories in page content using any `short code` or do I have any plugin to achieve this.

Comment: you can just use categories item available in the menu section.https://cloudup.com/caau8OMElEO

Answer (score 0):

You can add category item Current Tenders in your menu directly which shows all the post of your category Current Tenders.